# Are the new Dragon Ball movies canon?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

The new Dragon Ball movies (Battle of gods, Resurrection of Freezer, and the new Dragon Ball Super movie coming in December 2018) have directly involvement of Akira Toriyama, unlike the original movies which were made by Toei and had no involvement of Toriyama at all. Are these new Dragon Ball movies canon unlike the original ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *"Battle of Gods"*  and *Ressurection of Freiza"* were both implemented in the anime, hence they are obviously canon. However, certain aspects of the movies have been retconned in the anime for example

- Beerus utilising **10% of his power** against an SSJ2 enraged Vegeta.
- SSJG Goku being equal to **70%** of Beerus's Power.
- More emphasis has been laid on Gohan being weaker in the anime.
- Piccolo is killed by Freiza in the anime.

The new movie coming out in December is supposed to be set after the end of the *Tournament of Power* i.e Dragon Ball Super. We know this based on recent comments from Akira Toriyama. Hence it is obvious that the new movie might very likely be canon as well. I've attached a source with regard to the same [here](http://www.kanzenshuu.com/).

Comment: Since Akira Toriyama was more involved in the movies than in the anime, shouldnt the movies be "more canon" than the anime?